# How to remove all matched strings in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a problem, here is the description:
     There is a string, I am asked to delete all the matched substrings. For example,

```
s="asdf", sub_str=["as", "d"]
```

the result is `"f"`

```
s="aacc", sub_str=["ac"]
```

the result is `""`

```
s="abcf", sub_str=["ac", "b"]
```

the result is `"f"`

Could AnyOne help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Are you aware of the `replace` builtin method for strings? Your second example appears to loop over the `sub_str` list twice, do you intend for all the `sub_str` lists to be looped until there're no more replacements to be made?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: First, `"b"` is a match, then in the remain string `"acf"`, `"ac"` is a match, as a result, the left string is `"f"`

Comment: It's not that easy, when you replace a sub string, there may be new match for the previous substrings

Comment: In that case you might want a while loop that checks if the string contains any of your sub strings and keeps looping until it doesn't

Comment: I didn't say it was easy, just offering a few different alternative methods that might be worth thinking about. In the absence of any evidence of an attempt by you to solve this problem. If you don't provide evidence of your attempt, then the responses you get mightn't be all that helpful.

Comment: @Enrico'sRicardo what should be the answer if `s="abcf"` and `sub_str = ["fb"]` ?

Comment: `"abcf"` because `"fb"` doesn't appear in `"abcf"`

Comment: @Enrico'sRicardo You need to tag, else I won't be notified. Also, your accepted answer is incorrect(until the OP corrects it).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python delete substring", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Demo:**

```
import re

def removeString(sVal, sub_str):
    pat = re.compile("(" + "|".join(sub_str) + ")")
    m = pat.search(sVal)
    while m:
        sVal = re.sub(pat, "", sVal)
        m = pat.search(sVal)
    return sVal

#Testing....

s="asdf" 
sub_str=["as", "d"]
print(removeString(s, sub_str))

s="aacc" 
sub_str=["ac"]
print(removeString(s, sub_str))

s="abcf"
sub_str=["ac", "b"]
print(removeString(s, sub_str))
```

**Output:**

```
f

f
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The ordering of the substrings we evaluate also matters. Take `s="dsa"` and `sub_str=["d", "dsa"]`. The answer should be an empty string, but it gives `sa`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for sub_element in sub_str:
    for sub_char in sub_element:
        s = s.replace(sub_char, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need to remove any character present on the strings of `sub_str`, the most straightforward thing to do is the following:

```
def remove(s, sub_str):
    result = s
    for ss in sub_str:
        for c in ss:
            result = result.replace(c, "")
    return result


s = "asdf"
sub_str = ["as", "d"]

print(remove(s, sub_str))
```

**Output**

```
f
```

Comment: After you replace a sub string, there may be a new match for the previous substrings, for example, `"abc"`, first, you search `"ac"`, there is no match, then you search `"c"`after replacing `"b"` with space, the left string `"ac"`is a new match which cannot be replaced,

Comment: @Enrico'sRicardo What does fafter mean? Could you be more specific? I ran my function in all the inputs and it matched the expected output.

Comment: Why you first search "ac"?

Comment: Just a sample, you cannot just expect the order of the input sub strings

Comment: @Enrico'sRicardo Can you add an example where my functions breaks?

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` module, assuming that you are repeating removal until no change happen:

```
s="asdf", sub_str=["as", "d"]
f1=re.sub('|'.join(sub_str),'',s)
f2=re.sub('|'.join(sub_str),'',f1)
while f1!=f2:
    f1=f2
    f2=re.sub('|'.join(sub_str),'',f1)
f=f2
print(f) #prints 'f'
```